# Height in CSS not detected

Tags: html, css, image

I'm adding a CSS into my header however the only flaw left is the height attributes not being detected by the phone.

Here's how i link my header with css.

```
<div id="header">
 <img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" id="image">
</div>
```

Here's my CSS.

```
#header{
 position:absolute;    
}

#image{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:5%;
 height:50%;
}
```

Unfortunately, i dont see any thing wrong with the codes here.

Comment: you set `height:120%` but 120% of what?

Comment: that's the problem :( i added a height under the header but the header will disappear in my mobile phone. which means if i add 2 height in both header and image, the image disappears.

Comment: seems unclear your explanation the header will disappear? add 2 height?

Comment: Very unclear what you want.And you can remove img tag from header..I don't understand what is use of displaying header of 120% img in it

Comment: let me rephrase my question. When i added a height attribute on both `#header` and `#image` tags, the image will disappear like as if it's not there at all. After removing the height attribute on either of the `#header` and `#image` tags, the image appears again.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate actually the percentage isn't the problem though. just that my webapp did not detect and read the height attribute in my CSS.

Comment: The `%` heights need some requirements to work ... like all parents have a definition in `%` of some other value. And since you are using absolute position need to identify the parent of header and define height on header

Comment: @Danko What you meant was by right the `#header` should have a `height:%;` right?

Comment: All change based on the whole structure if you need % in header then the some parent need to have a fixed height in px to take in care those % values at some point .... or % in relation to the whole window

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
html,body{
   height:100%; /* add this*/
}
#header{
  position:absolute;    
  height:100%; /* add this*/
}
```

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vN6TR/1/)

**Why you need this??** beacuse `#image` has `height` set in percentage, in that case, it will look to its parent div for height, which is `#header`.....so set a height of all the elements if you are going to use them in percentages!!

**Another error :** you have mentioned `<div id=header>`, it should be `<div id="header">` (*notice quotes*)

Comment: but i dont have any body tag.

Comment: Even if you don't have a body-tag in your html, it'll be one _implicitly_ opened. The CSS will be applied.

Comment: You don't have a body tag? Than you have invalid HTML.

Comment: wait. you mean add the body in my CSS?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan : mate...just `view source` of any webpage....u'll understand! **OR** check this link http://www.sencha.com/learn/html-page-setup/ to undertsand the setup of html page....or google it dude!! :)

Comment: However, the problem is, when i add `height` attribute on both my `#header` and `#image` the image will disappear on my mobile. However, if i remove the `height` attribute from the `#image`, the image will re-appear again.

Comment: I do have the body but unfortunately, after adding that line of code, it still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan : mmm...ideally it *should* work....can you just update ur css in a fiddle and post its link???

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do this and seperate your header and body content.

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <img src="something" id="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Oops now i cant delete this answer too.

Comment: Why can't you delete your question?

Comment: because there's an answer that prevent me from deleting the question

Comment: Very unclear what you want.And you can remove img tag from header..I don't understand what is use of displaying header of 120% img in it